# How to swap JButtons after a period of time?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

How can I swap two JButtons after a period of time? I have a project in which I have to swap more than 2 buttons after period of time.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please check out [ask] and [mcve] to improve your question, which will help in getting helpful answers.

Comment: What have you tried? SO is not here to perform your assignments.

Answer (score 0):

> I have to swap more than 2 buttons after period of time.

Use a `Swing Timer` to schedule the swapping of the buttons. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more information and examples to get you started.

You may also want to use a `CardLayout`. It allows you to swap panels containing different components. So, when the Timer fires you just swap the panel. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more information.